# Fill ArrayList using for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an arrayList of a class named City with only parameters a city name in the following way:

```
static ArrayList<City> citiesList = new ArrayList<City>() ;
```

and i want in another class to fill this arrayList via a text field that i have passed as a parameter called name.What i have done is this(note the system out print is for my convinience to check the output):

```
public void createCity(String name) {
        if(ApplicationFx.citiesList.isEmpty()) {
            ApplicationFx.citiesList.add(new City(name));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<ApplicationFx.citiesList.size();i++) {
            if(!ApplicationFx.citiesList.get(i).getCityName().equals(name)) {
                System.out.println(i +  "   " + ApplicationFx.citiesList.get(i).getCityName() + " " + name);
                ApplicationFx.citiesList.add(new City(name));
                
            }
        }
        
    }
```

the method createCity gets called by an event handler in case the add City button is pressed,my problem is that i want to check whether a certain name already exist but instead when i run the code i get the following printed in the console:

```
0    CITY1    CITY2
0    CITY1    CITY3
0    CITY1    CITY4
0    CITY1    CITY5
0    CITY1    CITY6
```

note that CITY1 is my first input that i do not have a sysout.Any solutions?.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Define an appropriate `equals()` method in your `City` class, and then either use a `Set` instead of a `List`, or check `City newCity = new City(name); if (! citiesList.contains(newCity)) { ... }`.

Comment: Ok i will try this now :)

Comment: nope i cant get it to work.Also i need this to get done with arrayLists

Comment: the list is needed so then i can take the list and change it in other classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only property of the `City` class is the name, it makes sense to define an `equals` method that compares the name:

```
import java.util.Objects ;

public class City {

    private final String name ;

    public City(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return name ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true ;
        if (! (o instanceof City)) return false ;
        return Objects.equals(((City) o).getCityName(), name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

Then all you need is

```
public void createCity(String name) {
    City newCity = new City(name);
    if(! ApplicationFx.citiesList.contains(newCity)) {
        ApplicationFx.citiesList.add(newCity);
    }
}
```

If for some reason that `equals()` method is not appropriate for your class, you can do

```
public void createCity(String name) {
    for (City city : ApplicationFx.citiesList) {
        if (city.getCityName().equals(name)) return ;
    }
    ApplicationFx.citiesList.add(new City(name));
}
```

Comment: is there any way to explain how this works because i am a littile lost with that return.Thank you in advance

Comment: @OutOfBounds `return` just exits the method immediately.

Comment: also i there any way to tell what i had done wrong because i cant seem to find it :(.

Comment: @OutOfBounds Just step through your code with a debugger (though, I can't reproduce that output from your code).